# GOPATH not set correctly

Tags: ubuntu, go

i was installed go on xubuntu. after that iI change the GOPATH on

```
$ export GOPATH=$HOME/go
$ echo $GOPATH
$ /home/rangga/go
```

if I do go run

```
$ go run /home/rangga/go/src/Test/testpath.go
$ /home/rangga
```

i used `os.Getwd()` for test the current path

it should be the output like these `/home/rangga/go/src/Test`

FYI, here's my go env

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/rangga/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/gccgo/tool"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

do i made wrong in export GOPATH?, please how to make the GOPATH is workable on go language?

thank you

**EDIT**
ok, this is my mistake i should change to the current work directory after then do go run

thanks to peterSO

Comment: `Getwd` is the working directory, not the directory containing the file that's the argument to `go run`.  It's the equivalent of executing `pwd` in your shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Package os](https://golang.org/pkg/os/)
>
> [func Getwd](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getwd)
>
> ```
> func Getwd() (dir string, err error)
> ```
>
> Getwd returns a rooted path name corresponding to the current
>   directory. If the current directory can be reached via multiple paths
>   (due to symbolic links), Getwd may return any one of them.

```
$ go run /home/rangga/go/src/Test/testpath.go
$ /home/rangga
```

You got what you asked for, your current directory: `/home/rangga`.

Change your current directory,

```
$ cd /home/rangga/go/src/Test/
$ go run testpath.go
$ /home/rangga/go/src/Test
```

Comment: thanks for fast response. i have another OS installed on my PC, the other one is windows, when I called Getwd function the path is correctly to my GOPATH as i set already. ok I will try, thanks